# Localhost https breaks with nodeJS version update

Tags: reactjs, node.js, ssl, localhost, vite

All,

Have a naive looking problem: I have an application (react/viteJS) compiled in node16 and we run the app on https using mkcert on local machines. The app runs just fine. Now comes the udpate part. We udpated our app to nodeJS version 20 (and corresponding packages) and we keep getting this

```
This site can’t be reached admin.localhost.com refused to connect.
```

In the host files, we have the below

```
127.0.0.1       portal.localhost.com
127.0.0.1       admin.localhost.com
```

**Again, this all works when switched to nodeJS 16.**

Answer (score 1):

Node v20 prefers `ipv6` over `ipv4` addresses. You can try adding the `ipv6` address into you `hosts` file:

```bash
::1       portal.localhost.com
::1       admin.localhost.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with the vite.js configuration. For some reason, it specifically needed host to be set to "localhost.com" and surprisingly worked without that in node16!